# how to change SharePoint search page URL?

Tags: search, sharepoint-2007, windows-server-2008

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. I am using publishing portal template.

By default, the search page is using results.aspx as the search result page. I want to change results.aspx to another page (my custom search page to show results, e.g. customsearchresults.aspx), how to change?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look here: [Creating a custom search results page for a (searchresults.aspx) Windows Sharepoint Services (WSS) Site](http://theengineroom.provoke.co.nz/archive/2007/05/11/creating-a-custom-search-results-page-for-a-searchresults-aspx-windows-sharepoint-services-wss-site.aspx)

Another link: [Working With SharePoint Search - Part 1](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/sharepoint-blog/working-with-sharepoint-search-part-1-14359). See step 13.

Comment: Cool, I will try tomorrow and let you know the experiment result!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to create a "Search center" site (can be a subsite of your actual site)and create your search input/results pages there. Then you configure the search results page at *yoursite*/_layouts/enhancedSearch.aspx

Comment: I am confused. If I create a subsite of my main site dedicated for search, then how to configure the main site to use the subsite to do search other then using the search box (at the top-right corner) of the main site itself?

Comment: The "search results page" setting in enhancedSearch.aspx changes the way the search box works - your searches will be directed to your custom search center. You can customize your search center to show results in customsearchresults.aspx page
Another thing - when you define search scopes, each scope can have a different results page defined by you. Maybe this is worth a try.